# Printing multiple lines in a window using PyQT5 and Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to code a very simple window application. I want it to print some "output" in a part of a window (or in a new one - it doesn't matter).

I will try to better explain my problem using the code below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QSize, QRect

class PrintWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title='Print many lines'
        self.left=10
        self.top=10
        self.width=640
        self.height=480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('In progress')

        label1 = QLabel("Choose how many lines would you like to print:", self)
        label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(label1.x(), label1.y(), label1.width()+150, label1.height()))
        label1.move(10, 20)    

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)          
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)  

        self.comboBox = QComboBox(centralWidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40, 491, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(("comboBox"))
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("10")
        self.comboBox.addItem("50")
        self.comboBox.addItem("100")
        self.comboBox.move(10, 60)

        button_search = QPushButton('PRINT', self)
        button_search.clicked.connect(self.PrintFunction)
        button_search.resize(200,50)
        button_search.move(220,300)  

        self.show()

    def PrintFunction(self):
        x = self.comboBox.currentText()
        if len(x) == 0:
            x = 0
        else:
            x = int(x)

        for i in range(1, x+1):
            print('That is line number: ', i, ' , ', x - i, ' more line(s) to print.')

        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PrintWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Basically it does what I want but in the terminal window. I would like a new window in my application to be created (or a TextBox in the same window, whatever) after clicking "PRINT" button with those prints statements.

I am quite new to PyQT5 so I'm looking for simplest solutions (even if they are less effective).

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

I changed your code a bit, to reposition the button, then I inserted a QTextEdit below the button.
In your print function I modified the code, to write the output into the text edit.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QSize, QRect

class PrintWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title='Print many lines'
        self.left=10
        self.top=10
        self.width=640
        self.height=480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('In progress')

        label1 = QLabel("Choose how many lines would you like to print:", self)
        label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(label1.x(), label1.y(), label1.width()+150, label1.height()))
        label1.move(10, 20)    

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)          
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)  

        self.comboBox = QComboBox(centralWidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40, 491, 31))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(("comboBox"))
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("10")
        self.comboBox.addItem("50")
        self.comboBox.addItem("100")
        self.comboBox.move(10, 60)

        button_search = QPushButton('PRINT', self)
        button_search.clicked.connect(self.PrintFunction)
        button_search.resize(200,50)
        button_search.move(220,150)  

        # create textbox
        self.textbox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(50, 210)
        self.textbox.resize(540, 200)
        self.textbox.setReadOnly(true);
        # create textbox done

        self.show()

    def PrintFunction(self):
        x = self.comboBox.currentText()
        if len(x) == 0:
            x = 0
        else:
            x = int(x)

        # Aggregate text and fill textbox
        data = []
        for i in range(1, x+1):
            data.append('That is line number: ' + str(i) + ' , ' + str(x - i) + ' more line(s) to print.')
        self.textbox.setText("\n".join(data))
        # Aggregate text and fill textbox done

        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PrintWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look and then ask if needed :)

Comment: I would use formatted strings in `PrintFunction` instead of string concatenation, e.g. `data.append(f'That is line number: {i}, {x - i} more line(s) to print.')`.

Comment: I would do a lot different, but wanted to change as little as possible, as the OP asked for it

Answer (score 1):

Create a label just like you did with `label1`, but set its name to be accessible on the class level naming it like `self.output`. I'm following your logic, but you should read about layouts (here's [a nice tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/) for you):

```
self.output = QLabel(" ", self)
self.output.setWordWrap(True)
self.output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.output.x(), self.output.y(), self.output.width()+150, self.output.height()))
self.output.move(10, 120)
```

And then instead of:

```
for i in range(1, x+1):
        print('That is line number: ', i, ' , ', x - i, ' more line(s) to print.')
```

do:

```
mystr = ""
for i in range(1, x+1):
    mystr += 'That is line number: ', i, ' , ', x - i, ' more line(s) to print.\n'
self.output.setText(mystr)
```